# how can I fix Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 2 directives in flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have import 2 directives
[import directives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SasDT.png)

and use  prefix.DatePicker [use directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKIc.png), but when i run, it still notify error, please help me
[notify error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWFv9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKIc.png) you provided, the error specified `this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),`

You simply didn't use the prefix in that line.
It might have been overlooked accidentally because the line isn't in the image of the source code.